# Navigating directories when you don't know the name of the directory

Tags: unix, terminal

I have a directory that is created through an external process. The directory is named `2021-12-08_1345` (YYYY-MM-DD_HHMM) based on the date and time when the process is executed. While this is the only directory in the path, I won't know the precise name of the directory. Is there a way to navigate to this folder knowing that it's the first and only directory?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is `cd $(ls -d -1 */ |sed -n '1p')` where `1p` is the nth directory that you want to navigate to. I came across the solution on an Ubuntu StackExchange https://askubuntu.com/questions/454688/how-do-you-cd-into-the-first-available-folder-without-typing-out-the-name#comment1800653_455113

I verified that this works on macOS 11.5.2+

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure it is the only directory you can use

```
cd */
```

or

```
cd /path/to/*/
```

but this will fail if there is more than one directory.

Otherwise I suggest to use the solution from Ed Knittel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70285019/10622916).

If you know that there is only one directory and *no files* you can even omit the trailing `/` from these commands, e.g. `cd *`.